# CSS child element avoid parent overflow: scroll;

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, dropdown

I have a **parent** element that have inside multiple type of inputs and a horizontal scroll if the number of elements is bigger than width of the **parent**.

The problem is that when I build the **multiple select dropdown** element, the actual *drop down* doesn't get out from parent element, because of the overflow. When you click on *Make a selection* input, to be able to show the actual dropdown and choose options.

How I can solve this problem?

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/dukkevin/pen/xxJELbq)

```js
/* Multi Select Input JS */

//helper functions

function isOutsideNodeAndChildren($node, e) {
  // if the target of the click isn't the container...
  // nor a descendant of the container
  if (!$node.is(e.target) && $node.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
// constructor definition
function MultiSelect($select) {
  this.$select = $select;
  this.$outer;
  this.$field;
  this.$optionList;
  this.$options;

  this.isActive = false;

  this.createMultiSelectOption = function (optionText, fieldName) {
    var option = document.createElement("div");
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");

    option.className = "multi-select_option";
    option.tabIndex = -1;

    checkbox.className = "multi-select_checkbox";
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.tabIndex = "-1";
    checkbox.name = fieldName;

    label.className = "multi-select_label";
    label.htmlFor = fieldName;
    label.textContent = optionText;
    label.value = optionText;

    option.appendChild(checkbox);

    option.appendChild(label);

    return option;
  };
  this.toggleSelected = function ($option, e) {
    var $allCheckedOptions;
    var numChecked;
    var checkBox = $option.find(".multi-select_checkbox")[0];
    var $field = $option.parents(".multi-select").find(".multi-select_field");

    if (e.target.type !== "checkbox") {
      if (checkBox.checked) checkBox.checked = false;
      else checkBox.checked = true;
    }

    $allCheckedOptions = $option
      .parent()
      .find(".multi-select_option")
      .has(":checked");
    numChecked = $allCheckedOptions.length;

    if (numChecked) {
      $field.removeClass("is-empty");
      if (numChecked < 2) {
        $field.text($allCheckedOptions.find(".multi-select_label").text());
      } else {
        $field.text(numChecked + " selected");
      }
    } else {
      $field.addClass("is-empty");
      $field.text("Make a selection");
    }
  };

  this.activate = function (that) {
    this.$outer.addClass("is-active");
    this.$optionList.addClass("is-open");
    this.isActive = true;

    // make any click outside of the active multiselect close it.
    $(document).on("click.closeMulti", function (e) {
      if (isOutsideNodeAndChildren(that.$outer, e)) {
        that.deactivate();
      }
    });
  };
  this.deactivate = function () {
    // reset scroll position to top when opened again
    this.$optionList.scrollTop(0);

    this.$outer.removeClass("is-active");
    this.$optionList.removeClass("is-open");
    this.isActive = false;

    $(document).off(".closeMulti");
  };

  this.attachClickEvents = function (that) {
    this.$field.on("click", function (e) {
      // open options if not already open
      if (that.isActive) return;
      that.activate(that);
    });

    this.$options.on("click", function (e) {
      that.toggleSelected($(this), e);
    });
  };
  this.attachKeyboardEvents = function (that) {
    // enforce blur on tab when any part of multi is focused.

    this.$field.on("keydown", function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        that.deactivate();
        return;
      }

      if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        that.activate(that);
        that.$options.first().focus();

        // don't scroll the options list, let the focus handle that.
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    });

    this.$options.on("keydown", function (e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 9:
          that.deactivate();
          break;
        case 13:
          that.toggleSelected($(this), e);
          break;
        case 40:
          $(this).next().focus();

          // don't scroll the options list, let the focus handle that.
          e.preventDefault();
          break;
        case 38:
          $(this).prev().focus();

          // don't scroll the options list, let the focus handle that.
          e.preventDefault();

          break;
        default:
          // do nothing;
          break;
      }
    });
  };

  this.init = function () {
    var that = this;

    var $options = this.$select.find("option");
    var fieldName = this.$select.attr("name");

    var multiSelect = document.createElement("div");
    var field = document.createElement("div");
    var optionsList = document.createElement("div");

    multiSelect.className = "multi-select";
    field.className = "multi-select_field is-empty";
    field.tabIndex = 0;
    field.textContent = "Make a selection";
    optionsList.className = "multi-select_options";

    $options.each(function () {
      // if option is empty don't include it in the multi-select list
      if (!this.textContent) return;

      var o = that.createMultiSelectOption(this.textContent, fieldName);
      optionsList.appendChild(o);
    });

    multiSelect.appendChild(field);
    multiSelect.appendChild(optionsList);

    // replace regular dropdown w/ multi-select dropdown
    $(multiSelect).insertBefore(this.$select);
    this.$select.remove();
    this.$select = null;

    // cache multiSelect selectors
    this.$outer = $(multiSelect);
    this.$field = this.$outer.find(".multi-select_field");
    this.$optionList = this.$outer.find(".multi-select_options");
    this.$options = this.$outer.find(".multi-select_option");

    // attach multiSelect event handlers
    this.attachClickEvents(this);
    this.attachKeyboardEvents(this);
  };
}

// selectToMultiSelect plugin definition
$.fn.selectToMultiSelect = function (settings) {
  var m = new MultiSelect($(this));
  m.init();
};

$(".js-multi-select").selectToMultiSelect();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.multi-select {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.multi-select,
.multi-select *,
.multi-select *:before,
.multi-select *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.multi-select_field,
.multi-select_option {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
.multi-select_field {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  line-height: 25px;
  cursor: default;
}
.multi-select_field:hover {
  border-color: #888;
}
.multi-select_field:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.multi-select_field.is-empty {
  color: #aaa;
}
.multi-select_options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 170px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.is-active .multi-select_options {
  display: block;
}
.multi-select_option {
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 101;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.multi-select_option:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.multi-select_option:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.multi-select_label {
  position: relative;
}
.multi-select_checkbox {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <select name="foo" id="foo">
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
    </select>
    <select name="foo" id="foo">
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
      <option value="a">Select input</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dev" name="testField" id="1" class="js-multi-select">
      <option value="a">This is option 1</option>
      <option value="b">This is option 2</option>
      <option value="c">This is option 3</option>
      <option value="d">This is option 4</option>
      <option value="e">This is option 5</option>
      <option value="e">This is option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had this problem too. Take a look here: https://medium.com/@justicart/overflow-x-scroll-overflow-y-visible-c1a98238e002